# Virtual box-not filling entire screen even after installing aditional files

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I tried to full screen the ubuntu OS in vm box but even after installing additional files my screen had black background and it showed this error if i tried to install the additional file again.
Please suggest me some solution so that i can run the ubuntu OS in fullscreen in the VM Box.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/59s7J.png

Comment: Make sure the Virtual Box extensions have been installed in the Ubuntu Guest . It appears this has not been done